# pgrep search multiple words

Tags: linux, pgrep

I'm using `pgrep` to find running processes having some words

```
> pgrep -f "otp"
2345
2343
```

More than one process is identified. There is another word in the command line that would help me zero in to the exact process. So, I want to search for two terms and both should be there. Unfortunately I'm only seeing examples and help for OR combinations like this:

```
> pgrep -f "otp|place1"
2345
2343
3632
```

That does not work because it's an OR condition. I need an AND condition in my search pattern.

pgrep reference: https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep

> pattern: Specifies an Extended Regular Expression for matching against the process names or command lines.

How do I use pgrep to search for two words in AND combination instead of OR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found one way, with the condition being that they should be in order: separate the words by `.*`

```
> pgrep -f "otp.*place1"
2345
```

Answer (score 4):

I gave up on `pgrep` long ago. Always seemed like it should be more useful that what it ends up being.

This is what I use. A bit long winded, and always thought there must be a better way, so maybe someone can enlighten us both.

`egrep` allows for filtering with extended regular expressions which becomes important when you only want "one answer". `grep -E` is supposed to do the same thing but I got in the habit of using `egrep` because I wanted a solution which worked across multiple flavors of *nix.

The `-e` flag tells `ps` to show all processes (runs with permission of executing user. ie: not all procs show unless you are root). The`-f` flag tells `ps` to issue a "full-format" listing which you might need to `| less` when viewing it since longer CLI args might scroll off the right of the terminal and might not wrap. Hope it helps.

**Find processes matching `agetty`:**

```
# ps -ef | egrep agetty
root      1386     1  0 Sep19 ttyS0    00:00:00 /sbin/agetty --keep-baud 115200 38400 9600 ttyS0 vt220
root      1388     1  0 Sep19 tty1     00:00:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux
root     28332  4228  0 11:23 pts/2    00:00:00 grep -E agetty
```

**Find process matching `agetty` that also have `baud` in them:**

```
# ps -ef | egrep 'agetty.*baud'
root      1386     1  0 Sep19 ttyS0    00:00:00 /sbin/agetty --keep-baud 115200 38400 9600 ttyS0 vt220
root     28347  4228  0 11:23 pts/2    00:00:00 grep -E agetty.*baud
```

**Don't return my `grep` process. Not sure how it works but saves you from having to `| grep -v 'grep'` on the results. Maybe someone could explain this:**

```
# ps -ef | egrep 'agetty.*b[a]ud'
root      1386     1  0 Sep19 ttyS0    00:00:00 /sbin/agetty --keep-baud 115200 38400 9600 ttyS0 vt220
```

**egrep with the OR condition**

```
# ps -ef | egrep '(ag[e]tty|ac[p]id)'
root       944     1  0 Sep19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/acpid
root      1386     1  0 Sep19 ttyS0    00:00:00 /sbin/agetty --keep-baud 115200 38400 9600 ttyS0 vt220
root      1388     1  0 Sep19 tty1     00:00:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux
root     28395  4228  0 11:28 pts/2    00:00:00 grep -E (agetty|acpid)
```